# Modifying array directly in mongoose doesn´t works

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema with a field array.

I need to set the array field directly without get rid off the existent values.

I am using

```
item.files.concat(myfiles);
```

in the next code, but it doesn´t work. Only the last item from array is saved

//code

```
var files=['file1','file2','file3']
var myfiles=[]
files.forEach(function(file){                          
   myfiles.push({title:file});
  }
});
```

//router

```
 FileSchema.findById(id).exec( (err,item) => {
        //fill files -- error is here
       item.files.concat(myfiles);
        item.save(function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err)
          }
          res.send(data); //send response    
       })
  })
```

//schema

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const fileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {type: Number, unique:true},
  ...
  ...  
  files:[{title:{type: String}}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From MDN web docs:

> The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method **does not change the existing arrays**, but instead returns a new array.

```
item.files = item.files.concat(myfiles);
```

Comment: Thank  you. I solved it. I had to use item.markModified('files') with  mongoose